# Sails shows no error when model validation fails

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

in my production environment that uses MongoDB, whenever a model validation fails it shows nothing, while on my development environment with no database it shows something like this:

```
{
"error": "E_VALIDATION",
"status": 400,
"summary": "10 attributes are invalid",
"model": "Restaurant",
"invalidAttributes": {...}
}
```

I need my API to show these validation errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can return validation error as response:

#### For example (inside controller):

```
create: function (req, res, next) {
    ......
    User.create(data, function userCreated(err, user) {
      if (err)
        return res.negotiate(err);
      
      return res.ok({ user: user });
    }  
}
```

Comment: I was thinking on doing the same thing, will give it a try.